# Security with Laravel contact form. Is SSL needed?

Tags: security, laravel, ssl, laravel-5

So I made a contact form in Laravel 5, that's completely working. It basically posts the email, name and message to a variable and sends me an email with them. Is this secure enough for real life use without an SSL cert?

My project files are outside of the public_html folder if that makes a difference. I want to have this usable (security-wise), but don't want to pay a ton of money for an SSL cert on a site hardly anyone will go on.

Any answers appreciated

Comment: Just use HTTPS everywhere on your site. It's worth the practice. Few downsides.

Comment: There are cheap SSL certificates for your cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is always recommended, but if the contact form shouldn't get any sensitive data, then you can live without it.

Though now you can get SSL certs for free from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).